# IBM Maximo -email Listener

Tags: maximo

I have a problem about maximo e mail listener, some e mails are not red by maximo system and we cant see this emails inboundcomm. This happens to some emails, not all of them. ı controlled the cron tasks and system logs, but cant find anything. Anybody can help me ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this a programming question or a sysadmin one?

Comment: Which version of Maximo are you using?
Which operating system is the application server running on?
Have you tried upping the logging level for Email (EmailLsietnerCron -> DEBUG)
Are you seeing any errors in the SystemOut or SystemErr logs?
:)